# application.properties filtering is not working with spring.config.location

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I just tumbled upon a problem and I can not find any clues to solving it. Here is the problem, if I use `spring.config.location` to set a directory when running `mvn spring-boot:run` command like so
`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location=C:/conf/`
then properties do not get filtered. But if I do not declare `spring.config.location` and put application properties under resources folder then properties do get filtered. The said property I want to filter is a pom.xml tag which is project version and I've put it on application.properties folder as `my.project.version = @project.version@`. To be more precise, I get `0.0.0-RC2` when I don't declare a config location but I get `@project.version@` when I move my configurations to a location not under the project.

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version 2.5.6 as parent in my pom.xml